# identity proof by using combinatorics method

Tags: combinatorics

How can i prove that $\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{m-(k+1)}{p-k}= \binom{m}{p} $?
Of course I can use induction here but it's not very nice solution. Right hand side of equality is choosing $p$ people from set of $m$ people. How can I prove that left hand side is the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose the first $k$ people and then another $p-k$ from the last $m-(k+1)$.

Comment: You mean to say "Choose the first $k$ people" but don't choose the $k + 1$-th person. And then, choose another $p - k$ from the last $m - ( k + 1)$ to make the choices corresponding to different $k$ to be disjoint.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.  If you choose from the first $k$ and the last $m-(k+1)$, you didn't choose number $k+1$.